# Adobe Edge: Adding multiple projects into 1

Tags: compilation, adobe-edge, multiple-projects

I have made 11 separate edge projects and want to compile them into one using forward and back buttons. I can not find anything please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the CompositionLoader code here:
http://www.edgedocks.com/edgecommons

Or just put them all in Dreamweaver as oam files.